# How Neuromancer rating affects events in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

In Uplink, Neuromancer rating shows, how "good" you are. It decreased by doing academic, social and criminal data hacking, for example. But I could never neither see nor get, how does it change the gameplay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Neuromancer rating doesn't change anything at all, it simply shows how the hacker community feels about your activities - fighting corporations is good, harming individuals is bad.

Comment: I think it also biases the types of assignments that come your way.

Comment: @Shadur I doubt it, the listing is supposed to be global. Besides, whenever I try to keep my rating good, I always see dozens of jobs that would lower it.

Comment: @kotekzot But I do remember that after a while of doing college hacks and such, and declaring people dead that the other hacks started to get less frequent and those started to pop up alot more?