# How do missions that benefit individuals affect my Neuromancer rating?

Tags: uplink

According to this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129210/47878), your Neuromancer rating is increased when you harm corporations, but decreased when you harm individuals.

What about pro-individual missions?

- Improve our associates' academic standing
- Create part of a new identity
- Generate a University Degree for a friend
- Clear a criminal record

Do these increase or decrease my Neuromancer rating?

Answer (score 1):

"Improve our associates' academic standing", "Generate a University Degree for a friend" and "Clear a criminal record" all decrease your Neuromancer rating as far as I can tell.

I've just had my rating decrease to Neutral after clearing someone's criminal record, and I remember I had the same happen when generating or improving an university degree (it was one or the other, can't remember, but I would be surprised if both didn't behave the same way as per your Neuromancer rating).

I wouldn't be too hasty grouping "Create part of a new identity" with the others however, since it targets deceased people's records and could be seen as a pro-hacking move. Unfortunately, I have yet to see a rating change when running these missions.

Note that the easiest way to test it is to run the mission just after having had a Neuromancer rating increase : since increases are smaller than decreases, if you don't lose your rating it means the mission is good (or neutral? not sure there are any) for your Neuromancer rating.